# Is there such a control to display images

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there such a control that will allow me to arrange a collection of images like a deck of cards facing the user. To navigate, the user swipes the top left corner down to change the image view. Is there such a control? Is it possible to make one? How? If not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grid view is what you are looking for. Look at [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html), and try the sample.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I wanted although it displays images in rows and columns. What I wanted is a control like a desk of cards, you see only the One image at a time and swipe on it to see the next. Thanks.

Comment: Desk of cards? You probably mean "deck of cards"